# for-Loop to creat LinePlots with seaborn in DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, plot, seaborn

i am a beginner with coding with python and i have a question:

This code works fantastic to creat a chart for each Column:

The Main DF is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EWob.png)

1- Removing Outliers:

```
def remove_outliers(df_in, col):
    q1 = df_in[col].quantile(0.25)
    q3 = df_in[col].quantile(0.75)
    iqr = q3-q1
    lower_bound = q1-1.5*iqr
    upper_bound = q3+1.5*iqr
    df_out = df_in.loc[(df_in[col] > lower_bound) & (df_in[col] < upper_bound)]
    return df_out
```

2- Define the Format of the Lineplot

```
rc={'axes.labelsize': 20, 'font.size': 20, 'legend.fontsize':20,'axes.titlesize':20,'xtick.labelsize': 14,'ytick.labelsize': 14, 'lines.linewidth':1, 'lines.markersize':7, 'xtick.major.pad':10}



sns.set(rc=rc)
```

3- Creat a Lineplot with seaborn:

```
df1_DH001= remove_outliers(main_df, 'DH001')[['DH 001','Datum']]

df1_DH001_chart= sns.scatterplot(x='Datum', y='DH 001', data=df1_DH001)
df1_DH001_chart= sns.lineplot(x='Datum', y='DH 001', data=df1_DH001, lw=3, color="b")

df1_DH001_chart.set(xlim=('1995','2019'), ylim=(0, 220) ,title='DH 001', ylabel='Nitrat mg/L', xlabel="Jahr")

df1_DH001_chart.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator(1))
df1_DH001_chart.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))

df1_DH001_chart
```

So I got this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnFOg.png)

Now I would like to creat a for-Loop to creat the same plot and the same x-Axis (Datum) but with another column (There are 22 Columns)

Could some one help me?

Answer (score 1):

Import the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
```

Create asample DF:

```
data = {'day': ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu'],
        'col1': [22000,25000,27000,35000],
        'col2': [2200,2500,2700,3500],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Select only numeric columns from your DF or alternatively select the columns that you want to consider in the loop:

```
df1 = df.select_dtypes([np.int, np.float])
```

Iterate through the columns and print a line plot with seaborn:

```
for i, col in enumerate(df1.columns):
    plt.figure(i)
    sns.lineplot(x='day',y=col, data=df)
```

Then the following pictures will be shown:

[image]

[image]